# How to disable sorting in PropertyGrid

Tags: .net, propertygrid

I want my items to appear in declaration order instead on alphabetical order.
Is it possible to disable sorting in PropertyGrid?

Comment: The reflection API *cannot guarantee* anything relating to declaration order: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kyaxdd3x.aspx - "The GetProperties method does not return properties in a particular order, such as alphabetical or declaration order. Your code must not depend on the order in which properties are returned, because that order varies."

Comment: @MarcGravell I use custom type descriptor and I build manually PropertyDescriptorCollection. I need them to be displayed in this particular order.

Comment: k - I thought by "declaration order" you meant code declaration order; if you are using a custom descriptor setup you should be fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `PropertySort` Enumeration.
Set it to `NoSort`.
Check this link for [details](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.propertysort.aspx)